# OpenSSL, decrypting with a private key

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

Okay, so I have a text file named Kryptert that is encrypted.
A key file named private with the private key. I want the output to be in a text file named Klartext.

I am about to rip my hair out, because I cannot seem to figure this out.

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey C:\private.key -in C:\Kryptert.txt -out C:\Klartext.txt
```

The command above is what I use, and I get the following output in the CMD windows:

```
C:\Users\Marco>openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey C:\private.key -in C:\Kryptert.txt -out C:\Klartext.txt
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
RSA operation error
8560:error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_pk1.c:190:
8560:error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed:.\crypto\rsa\rsa_eay.c:592:
```

Anyone able to help me understand what is wrong, and how I could fix it? Thank you.

Comment: What command was used to encrypt the file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here you have the commands you need to encrypt or decrypt using openssl:

Decrypt:

```
$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -in $ENCRYPTED -out $PLAINTEXT -inkey keys/privkey.pem
```

Encrypt:

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -in $PLAINTEXT -out $PLAINTEXT.encrypt -pubin -inkey keys/pubkey.pem
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It would appear (from the error message) that the format of the input is wrong, i.e. has the wrong padding.

Answer (score 16):

For encryption:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -in /path/to/your/file -out /path/to/your/encrypted -pubin -inkey /path/to/your/public_key.pem
```

For decryption:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in /path/to/your/encrypted -out /path/where/you/want/your/decrypted.txt -inkey /path/to/your/private_key.pem
```

**Note:** If you have this decryption error: `RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len`  try this command before decrypt your file:

```
cat yourEncryptedFile| base64 -D > yourEncryptedRawFile
```

More information [here](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Encrypt_and_decrypt_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html)

Comment: You have to use the base64-command with a lowercase `-d`, uppercase `-D` is invalid

Answer (score 2):

For versions 3.0 and above `rsautil` is deprecated. Use `pkeyutl` instead.
The usage stays the same for this example, i.e. (on Windows):

```
.\openssl.exe pkeyutl -decrypt -in .\encryptedfile -out decryptedfile -inkey .\private-key.pem
```

Side note:
I was playing around with TLS and wanted to decrypt the premaster key sent by the client in a TLS 1.0 (yes, TLS 1.0) handshake. In case someone tries the same: Copy the premaster key (which will be in a hexadecimal representation) into a text file, save it, and then convert the text file to a binary file using `certutil`. The output can then be used with openssl.

Example:

1. Convert premaster key's hexadecimal representation to binary:

```
certutil -decodehex -f .\premasterkey.txt premasterkey.bin
```

2. Decrypt using openssl

```
.\openssl.exe pkeyutl -decrypt -in .\premasterkey.bin -out decrypted.bin -inkey .\private-key.pem
```

3. (Optional) Convert the resulting binary into a hexadecimal representation again for viewing.

```
certutil -encodehex -f decrypted.bin decryptedinhex.txt
```